# appending multiple values to a key

Tags: python-2.7, list, dictionary

```
r =requests.get("https://www.federalreserve.gov/fomc/minutes/1994/19940706min.htm")
c = r.content
soup= BeautifulSoup(c)
dates=  soup.find_all("span", {"class" : "style1"})
committee = soup.find_all("div", {"class" : "committee" })
attendees= soup.find_all("div", {"class":"attendees"})
text = soup.find_all("p")
minutesDate = [i.get_text() for i in dates]
minutesCommittee = [j.get_text() for j in committee]
minutesAttendees = [k.get_text() for k in attendees]
minuteText=[m.get_text() for m in text]
new_dict = {k: v for k, v in zip(minutesDate, minutesCommittee)}
```

Using above code, I wanted to create a key of minutesDate and append other values - minutesCommittee, minutesAttendees, minuteText. I tried collection package with defaultdict and setdict, for some reason I am not being able to figure out how to tie those values to this one key.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a dict of dicts:

```
minutes = {minuteDate1: {minutesCommitee: [...], minutesAttendees = [...], ...},
           minuteDate2: {minutesCommitee: [...], minutesAttendees = [...], ...}}
```